# Drop Down in Angular

Tags: angular, dropdown

I was looking for a simple sample , how to bind a drop down. In net every one is creating a component, which I feel is not a practical solution in real life application

I am looking a simple language drop down inside login component from which user can select language

```
 export class LanguageListComponent  {

  selectedLanguage: Language;
  countries = [
    new Language(1, 'USA' ),
   new Language(2, 'India' ),
   new Language(3, 'Australia' ),
   new Language(4, 'Brazil'),
   new Language(5, 'Russia')
];
  }


 export class Language {
 constructor(public id: number, public name: string) { }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code is attached below**

**Template:**

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedCountryId" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
    <option [ngValue]="country.getId()" *ngFor="let country of countries">{{country.getName()}}</option>
</select>
```

**Class**

```
export class LanguageListComponent {
    countries = [
        new Language(1, 'USA' ),
        new Language(2, 'India' ),
        new Language(3, 'Australia' ),
        new Language(4, 'Brazil'),
        new Language(5, 'Russia')
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming id,name as properties of Language, you need to do below in html:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedLanguage">
  <option *ngFor="let c of countries" [ngValue]="c">{{c.name}}</option>
</select>
```